# How to define a Content Id on an attachment using azure-communication-email?

Tags: python, azure, azure-communication-services

I am using the [azure-communication-email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email?pivots=programming-language-python) library to send emails through the Azure service.

I need to add an image in base64 format as an attachment and define a Content Id to reference it in an `<img src="cid:myimagecid">` tag.

The problem is that EmailAttachment only allows to define:

```
attachment = EmailAttachment(
    name="attachment.png",
    attachment_type="png",
    content_bytes_base64=file_bytes_b64
)
```

Is there any way to define that Content Id in the attachment?

Comment: The is no content ID field available in the API for email attachments - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/email/send?tabs=HTTP#emailattachment. Feature requests can be added here https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/81ff6d2b-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way as of yet (Sept 2022), but please keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-dotnet-quickstarts/issues/51) on GitHub.